# What folders count as temporary folders?

Tags: windows, windows-10, temporary-files

What folders count as temporary folders for calculating the disk space used up by temporary files in Windows 10? (System->Storage in Settings)

So far, I know about:

**C:\Windows\Temp**
**C:\Users\USERNAME\Appdata\Local\Temp** (a.k.a. **%temp%**)
**C:\Windows\Prefetch**
**C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download**

I know there are more, because the sizes don't add up to the total. I already subtracted the size of Downloads, Recycle Bin, previous versions of Windows, and updates.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a list of what folders are used in the calculation, not including the four I already know.

Comment: You're probably looking for [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/junk-files-in-windows-10) rather than the actual location of temp folders. The Disk Cleanup includes other things like Temporary Internet Files.

Comment: any file with the extension .tmp is considered a temporary file by windows, you could search your folders for these and might give some insight.

Comment: @Moab this is helpful. Do you mean any .tmp file is counted in the total regardless of file path? What about .bak and .old?

Comment: @NotReallyHere12, no but may give clues to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Temporary Files in Windows are typically **found** located in two locations:

```
%systemdrive%\Windows\Temp

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

About other two locations, I don’t suggest to touch them

```
 C:\Windows\Prefetch
```

Prefetch is an algorithm that helps anticipate cache misses (times when Windows requests data that isn’t stored in the disk cache), and stores that data on the hard disk for easy retrieval.

If you actually delete the **Prefetch** folder, here’s what you should really expect to happen: Windows and applications will **need noticeably more time to start**, as the Prefetch data needs to be collected again. The entire performance of your system will slow down.

```
 C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
```

The `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download` folder is automatically maintained by the WUAgent. On the off-chance that the Datastore and the Download folder get de-synchronized, it may be necessary one-time-only to delete any content in the Download folder that is over 10 days old.

In addition, the Datastore contains all of the Windows Update History for the client system. Destroying the `SoftwareDistribution` folder, except when expressly warranted due to error conditions for which destruction of the `SoftwareDistribution` folder is the only solution, destroys the entire Windows Update History for that client system.

It also results in longer detection times at the next detection, because the WUAgent has to re-cache howeverMany thousands of available updates, as result of the destruction of the Datastore.

The best practice for free space is using built-in disk cleanup tool to delete Temporary files, the Temporary files here is regarded as temp files by system rather than us.

Comment: Interesting, but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Disk Cleanup options it will give you other things than just the Temp files you refer.

[image]

You're right about the 4 locations you already know, they are Temporary Files paths (and basically the only ones)

You still have more options:

- Temporary Internet Files (file path `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache` for Windows 8/10);
- Downloaded Program Files;
- Offline Webpages;
- Thumbnails
- etc.

You can also consider cookies, sessions (on browser) temporary files as well but Disk Cleanup doesn't really look for this files (except Edge/IE).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I know one more filepath now - do you know the others? I can only find 3/4 of the total. I'm looking for technical data about the calculation, not Disk Cleanup or other tools.